# Android голосовоее управление и google

Tags: android

Есть идея сделать приложение которое по умолчанию показывало бы часы, но в фоне ждала команд по типу "окей гугл" и выполняла запрограммированые действия, а если команды нету передавала бы этот запрос в google now который в свою очередь уже выполнял поиск в google и говорил и выводил запрос.
Распознаванием готовых запросов все более менее понятно, а вот как передать запрос в google now, не нашёл не где такой информации, что бы можно было при запуске google now ему можно было сразу передать запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Официально в google now нет API, которое бы позволяло передать ему запрос. Но неофициально - есть:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Ваш запрос");
startActivity(intent);
```

---

**П. С.** Нашел в [гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20start%20google%20now%20intent%20with%20query) за полторы минуты
**П. П. С** приложение [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) должно быть установлено в телефоне, чтобы это сработало. Иначе вылетит `Exception`